# Deutschkenntnisse verbessern (nach C2, verhandlungssicher, fließend)

Tags: vocabulary

Ich spreche seit über 20 Jahren Deutsch, und würde behaupten, dass ich fließend spreche. Ab und zu mal lese/höre ich Redewendungen oder Wörter, die ich nicht kenne, und die selten genutzt werden, aber schön und sehr genau sind.

Beispiele: allmählich, Kleinod...

Wo könnte ich sowas lernen?

Comment: (Ältere) Bücher lesen? Ich bin Muttersprachler und hatte keine Ahnung was ein Kleinod ist.

Comment: verhandlungssicher, fließend; Das ist nichts, dass man einfach so kann, nur weil man Muttersprachler ist. Das lernt man in speziellen Kursen oder mit der Zeit als Assistent von jemandem, der das sehr gut kann. Außerdem braucht es ein gewisses Talent dafür.

Comment: @mic in diesem Zusammenhang ist mit "verhandlungssicher" wohl eher gemient, dass bei Verhandlungen die (Fremd-)Sprache kein Hindernis darstellt. Ob man gut verhandeln kann oder nicht steht auf einem anderen Blatt.

Comment: @c.p.: Wie ist's mit "langsam"?

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage nicht. Was meinst du mit "Wo könnte ich so was lernen?" Willst du seltene Ausdrücke, die dir begegnen, nachschlagen? Oder willst du einen aktiven Wortschatz solcher Ausdrücke parat haben, um sie zu benützen? Oder suchst du einen speziellen Kurs zum Training geschliffenen, gewählten Ausdrucks?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Wenn ich solche Wörter lesen, nutze ich schon ein Wörterbuch. Aber am liebsten möchte ich solche Wörter auch einfach so lernen, damit mein Wortschatz einfach wächst und ich mich besser und genauer ausdrücken kann.

Comment: Dann ist die beste Methode: wenn dir so ein Ausdruck begegnet, der dir gefällt, dann schreib ihn auf einen Zettel ("Flashcard") oder einen Klebezettel (Post-it), und diese Zettel schaust du dir gelegentlich an, zum Beispiel beim Zähneputzen. Auf diese Weise lernst du Wörter, die dich interessieren, und das ist das Effektivste.

Answer (score 3):

**Zusammengefasst:** Es sollte ausreichen, eine Sprache aktiv zu praktizieren und mit verschiedenen Sprechern und Quellen in Kontakt zu kommen. Unbekannte Vokabeln, Wendungen und Idiome erklären sich meistens aus dem Kontext und werden so auch wesentlich leichter gelernt als durch ein theoretisches Studium.

Wie man am besten eine Sprache lernt, ist natürlich immer vom Kenntnisstand, den persönlichen Präferenzen und dem angestrebten Kenntnisumfang abhängig. In vielen Fällen reicht es aus, der Sprache ausgesetzt zu sein und jemanden zu haben, den man bei Unklarheiten fragen kann (heutzutage kann das auch die Suchmaschine des Vertrauens sein). **Selbst Muttersprachler kennen niemals alle Vokabeln, Sinnsprüche und Redewendungen ihrer Sprache.** Es gibt aber natürlich Leute mit größerem oder kleinerem Wortschatz. Diese unterscheiden sich unter anderem darin: Mit wie vielen unterschiedlichen Sprechern sie Kontakt haben und welche und wie viele unterschiedliche Texte, Filme, Inszenierungen etc. sie konsumieren. Außerdem hat man i.d.R. verschieden vielfältigen Wortschatz in verschiedenen Themenbereichen.

Davon ausgehend kann man umgekehrt sein Vokabular erweitern, indem man diese Punkte gezielt angeht. Man kann aktiv nach Gelegenheiten suchen, mit den verschiedensten Sprechern ins Gespräch zu kommen, kann seine (im wörtlichen oder übertragenen Sinn) Bibliothek in dieser Sprache erweitern oder sein Wissen in bestimmten Interessensgebieten verbessern um nebenbei spezielle Wörter und Wendungen lernen.

Ein wesentlich radikalerer Schritt wäre, die Sprache auf eine ähnliche Weise zu studieren, wie Spitzensportler (z.B. Weltklasseschachspieler) es mit ihrer Sportart tun. Das hieße im Fall einer Sprache: Thesauren lesen, Grammatik diskutieren, Beispiele Sammeln und analysieren, ... . Auf diese Weise wird man eine Sprache am vollständigsten lernen, der relative Nutzen ist aber minimal.

Hierzu empfehle ich die Vorträge von Vera Birkenbihl zum gehirngerechten (Sprachen-) Lernen. Sie adressiert zwar vor allem das Anfängerlevel, zeigt aber auch auf, wie der Weg weiter geht und wie die Gewichtung zwischen Theorie und Praxis auf den unterschiedlichen Kenntnisständen aussehen sollte. Kurz gesagt: in aller Regel reicht regelmäßige Praxis aus und Theorie ist nur für Neugierige oder Profis, die die Muße haben, ihre Fähigkeiten bis zur Meisterschaft zu bringen. Das braucht man weiß Gott nicht, denn selbst den meisten Muttersprachlern begegnen immer wieder unbekannte Idiome und der Kontext ist i.d.R. ausreichend, um sie zu verstehen. Ausnahmen tun erfahrungsgemäß auch nicht weh und können durch eine Nachfrage oder Internetsuche schnell geklärt werden.

Comment: *Selbst Muttersprachler kennen niemals alle Vokabeln, Sinnsprüche und Redewendungen ihrer Sprache.* Diesen Satz solltest Du am besten hervorheben, da er in Bezug auf die Frage besonders wichtig (und sehr zutreffend) ist.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf  Es kommt aber auch ein bisschen auf die Mutter an.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Selbstverständlich haben Menschen aus einem Elternhaus mit hoher Bildung (zumindest falls die Eltern sich auch mit den Kindern beschäftigen) einen weitaus größeren Wortschatz und umfassendere Kenntnisse von Redewendungen und dergleichen, aber niemand wird jemals 100% erreichen. Dafür sorgt allein schon die Existenz von Regionalismen.